# Oсtober CMS - Скрыть все записи в backend плагина кроме тех, которые доступны группе текущего пользователя

Tags: php, laravel, october, octobercms

Я создал небольшой плагин для **October CMS** с помощью Rainlab.Builder.

Он состоит из **2х моделей/контроллеров/таблиц в БД**.

---

**Branches** - Филиалы.

таблица: elisseiidev_branchmanagement_branches

---

**Groups** - Группы пользователей (менеджеров).

Стандартная таблица October CMS: backend_user_groups

---

При этом я использую ещё одну дополнительную таблицу для того что бы по ID связать записи в **Branches** с записями в **Groups**. 
Модель Groups берёт данные из стандартной October CMS таблички **backend_user_groups**

Объясню подробнее.

В RainLab.Builder сделал следующее:

1) Создал новое поле в модели Branches, 
Type: "Relations", 
Field name: groups

2) Создал таблицу в базе данных: elisseiidev_branchmanagement_branches_groups

3) Добавил в код модели Branches следующее:

```html
    public $belongsToMany =[ 

        'groups' =>[ 
            'Elisseiidev\BranchManagement\Models\Groups', 
            'table' => 'elisseiidev_branchmanagement_branches_groups', 
            'order' => 'name'
        ]

    ];
```

Сейчас в табличку записываются **group_id** и **branch_id** и таким образом они связываются. Это позволяет при создании новой записи в модели Branches  указывать к какой группе пользователей относится данная запись (Branch).

---

### **Теперь Вопрос:**

В **Backend** плагина мне необходимо **скрыть** все записи кроме тех, которые доступны текущему менеджеру.

Нужно использовать следующую логику:

Если **code/slug роли** текущего пользователя = '**manager**', а так же пользователю присвоена группа, **то...**
Создаём переменную **$userGroups** и записываем в неё **code/slug группы** или нескольких групп, к которым относится текущий пользователь.
Далее скрываем все записи, кроме тех, которые прикреплены к группе, название которой совпадает с названием группы текущего пользователя.

Надеюсь понятно это всё объяснил.

Подозреваю что нужно как то расширить контроллер, но не знаю как, так как в Laravel пока не силён.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно смотреть в сторону scope.

https://octobercms.com/docs/database/model#query-scopes
https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/relations#configuring-relation ищите по слову scope
https://octobercms.com/forum/post/fields-relation-scope-cant-query-only-child